# Is it possible to create a linear map that goes from the surface of the Earth to a 2-d screen?

Tags: linear-algebra, cartography

There are many ways to map the surface of the Earth to a literal map one can see on a screen. The projections have pros and cons. It is well known that the Mercator projection distorts areas. But there are [equal area projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-area_projection) that preserve areas at the expense of angles.

In linear algebra, we have the concept of a linear map. It satisfies:
$$f(v+u) = f(v)+f(u)$$
$$f(c.v) = c. f(v)$$

My question - is it possible to project the surface of a 2-d sphere to a plane in a way that it is a linear map? And is that also possible for hyperbolic surfaces?

Comment: You question doesn't make much sense: the surface of a 2-d sphere is not closed under addition or scalar multiplication (assuming your sphere inherits those operations from the 3-space $\Bbb{R}^3$ it is embedded in).

Comment: [Projecting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) a sphere to a plane [has some constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium#Elementary_applications).

Answer (score 3):

Without further qualification, one could say this:

Any bijection from $\mathbb R^2\to \mathcal S^2$ can be used to transport a vector space structure to $\mathcal S^2$, and doing that makes the original map a linear isomorphism.

This somewhat disappointing answer highlights the fact that one can't really say anything interesting without first specifying what linear structure one wants to place on $\mathcal S^2$.

Now, a better way to go about this is to check out what a [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) is.  From that perspective, one would say that "$\mathcal S^2$ looks like $\mathbb R^2$ when you are up close to it."  From far away, though, the manifolds $\mathcal S^2$ and $\mathbb R^2$ are globally not alike.

Comment: So is a bijection from $S^2 \to R^2$ not even possible? But then what's wrong with observing that every point on the globe has a counterpart on a map of the world? Isn't that a 1:1 mapping?

Comment: @RohitPandey $\mathcal S^2$ and $\mathbb R^2$ clearly have the same cardinality, so there is a bijection between the two.  I did not suggest that bijections were scarce/nonexistant.  Such bijections are not really useful (beyond telling us the cardinality of $\mathcal S^2$, that is.)

Answer (score 0):

A sphere $\mathcal S^2$ is not a vector space so it does not make sense to speak of a linear map

$$ f : \mathcal S^2 \to \mathbb R^2.$$
Hence it is not possible to find such a linear map.

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @RobArthan I disagree. This answers the question. Hence it should not be posted as a comment since we should "avoid answering questions in comment" as per the site's policy

Comment: No. It's not an answer. The statement that a sphere is not a vector space makes assumptions about what the OP means. So your "answer" is making a guess about the meaning of the question and then stating a non sequitur: it is meaningless to talk about the linearity of a map whose domain is not equipped with an agreed vector space structure, so to say that it is not possible to find a linear map in such a case is meaningless too, but that is what your answer claims.

Comment: To put it another way, any bijection from $\mathbb R^2$ to the sphere could be said to give the sphere a vector space structure (by transport) and indeed that'd automatically be a linear isomorphism. So one cannot disprove it by saying "$\mathcal S^2$ is not a vector space" by fiat.  My guess is that the user has not mentioned, or is unaware they needed, conditions to make the problem better posed.

Comment: PS. I very rarely downvote MSE answers, but I did downvote this one for the reasons I gave.

Comment: I really appreciate the fact that you left a comment explaining the downvote. This is the correct way to downvote in my mind and almost no one does this.